# Crontab can not run Python script because the python file have third-party lib

Tags: python, cron

I have the following crontab:

```
22 * * * * cd /home/work/ui && /home/work/.jumbo/bin/python test.py >> result.log &
```

And the `test.py` have the following codes:

```
#!/home/work/.jumbo/bin/python
#coding=utf-8

import datetime
import hashlib
import logging
import os
import Queue
import signal
import sys
import threading
import time
import traceback

#注释

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'Begin'
    print 'End'
```

OK, the codes can run right, but I add `import requests` after, it will not run right, I think that it can not find lib path.

So, I use `sys.path.append`, but it still can not run right.

```
#!/home/work/.jumbo/bin/python
#coding=utf-8

import datetime
import hashlib
import logging
import os
import Queue
import signal
import sys
import threading
import time
import traceback

sys.path.append('/home/work/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests')
print sys.path

import requests

#注释

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'Begin'
    print 'End'
```

And then, how do I it?

**BTW, I can run it right on OS command.** So my code is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron jobs start with a very limited set of environment variables.
There's likely one or more environment variables you get from your ~/.profile or ~/.login (or the like).

Try moving the whole job into a script and invoke it like this:

```
22 * * * * /home/work/ui/mycronjob
```

In `mycronjob` you'd have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile
cd /home/work/ui && /home/work/.jumbo/bin/python test.py >> result.log
```

That assumes your $SHELL is bash and you have a ~/.bash_profile.
If you have some other shell or other init file (~/.login, ~/.profile, etc) use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

first a tip: 
you can redirect stderr as well as stdout to a log file in crontab like this:

```
22 * * * * cd /home/work/ui && /home/work/.jumbo/bin/python test.py >> result.log 2>&1
```

I think the path to be appended should be

```
sys.path.append('/home/work/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

Comment: Thanks, I use `source` and can run OK